# Force SQL query to put results of 2 CASE statements into the same row

Tags: sql, case

I have a SQL query which, among other things, lists a Document ID, Category of Work, Outcome to Provider, then a couple of calculated fields.

Category of Work (COW) and Outcome to Provider (OTP) are the results of two case statements which basically says:

MAX(CASE WHEN prompt = 'Outcome to Provider' then lookup_name ELSE NULL END) AS OTP,

MAX(CASE WHEN prompt = 'Category of Work' THEN lookup_name ELSE NULL END) AS COW

When this runs, it puts the results for OTP and COW on separate rows.  I'm trying to get these on the same row.  I've tried using MAX and not using MAX, fiddling around with Tablix properties (this query is part of the dataset for an SSRS report) and just can't get it to work...PLEASE HELP!

The entire query is here:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.last_name, actors_groups.group_uid, groups.name AS group_name, users.actor_uid, users.first_name, documents.document_uid, 
                      documents.document_format_uid, 1 AS document_event_definition_uid, groups.group_type_uid, a.event_date AS event_date, 
                      a.event_date AS local_event_date, actors.account_name, documents.document_id, users_1.last_name AS SupeLName, 
                         users_1.first_name AS SupeFName,
                         MAX(CASE WHEN sf_system_prompts.prompt = 'Outcome to Provider' THEN sf_system_lookup_values.lookup_name ELSE NULL END) AS OTP,
                         MAX(CASE WHEN sf_system_prompts.prompt = 'Category of Work' THEN sf_system_lookup_values.lookup_name ELSE NULL END) AS COW
FROM         document_events a
inner join [dbo].[document_event_definitions] b
 on a.document_event_definition_uid=b.document_event_definition_uid
 inner join document_events c
 on a.document_event_uid=c.document_event_uid 

INNER JOIN
                      users AS users WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.actor_uid = users.actor_uid INNER JOIN
                         users AS users_1 ON users.supervisor_uid = users_1.actor_uid  INNER JOIN
                      actors_groups AS actors_groups WITH (NOLOCK) ON users.actor_uid = actors_groups.actor_uid INNER JOIN
                      groups AS groups WITH (NOLOCK) ON actors_groups.group_uid = groups.group_uid INNER JOIN
                      documents AS documents WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.document_uid = documents.document_uid INNER JOIN
                      actors WITH (NOLOCK) ON users.actor_uid = actors.actor_uid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      sf_pages AS sf_pages WITH (NOLOCK) ON documents.document_uid = sf_pages.document_uid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      sf_combo_values as sf_combo_values WITH (NOLOCK) ON sf_pages.sf_page_uid=sf_combo_values.sf_page_uid left outer join
                      sf_system_lookup_values AS sf_system_lookup_values WITH (NOLOCK) ON sf_combo_values.sf_system_lookup_value_uid=sf_system_lookup_values.sf_system_lookup_value_uid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      sf_system_lookup_values AS sf_system_lookup_values_1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON sf_combo_values.sf_system_lookup_value_uid=sf_system_lookup_values_1.sf_system_lookup_value_uid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      sf_system_lookup_tables AS sf_system_lookup_tables WITH (NOLOCK) ON sf_system_lookup_tables.sf_system_lookup_table_uid = sf_system_lookup_values.sf_system_lookup_table_uid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      sf_system_prompts as sf_system_prompts WITH (NOLOCK) ON sf_system_prompts.sf_system_lookup_table_uid = sf_system_lookup_tables.sf_system_lookup_table_uid
WHERE     event_name='Originated' and (groups.group_type_uid = 1) AND (groups.group_uid = 1000) AND (actors.account_name IN (@Users)) AND (cast(c.event_date as date) BETWEEN 
                      @StartDateAdj AND @EndDateAdj) AND (users.supervisor_uid IN (@aSupeList))
GROUP BY users.last_name, actors_groups.group_uid, groups.name, users.actor_uid, users.first_name, documents.document_uid, documents.document_format_uid, groups.group_type_uid, a.event_date, 
actors.account_name, documents.document_id, users_1.last_name, users_1.first_name, sf_system_prompts.prompt, sf_system_lookup_values.lookup_name
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT      users.last_name, actors_groups.group_uid, groups.name AS group_name, users.actor_uid, users.first_name, documents.document_uid, 
                      documents.document_format_uid, 4 AS document_event_definition_uid, groups.group_type_uid, a.event_date AS event_date, 
                      a.event_date AS local_event_date, actors_1.account_name, documents.document_id, users_1.last_name AS SupeLName, 
                         users_1.first_name AS SupeFName,
                         MAX(CASE WHEN sf_system_prompts.prompt = 'Outcome to Provider' THEN sf_system_lookup_values.lookup_name ELSE NULL END) AS OTP,
                         MAX(CASE WHEN sf_system_prompts.prompt = 'Category of Work' THEN sf_system_lookup_values.lookup_name ELSE NULL END) AS COW
FROM         document_events a
inner join [dbo].[document_event_definitions] b
 on a.document_event_definition_uid=b.document_event_definition_uid
 inner join document_events c
 on a.document_event_uid=c.document_event_uid INNER JOIN
                      users AS users WITH (NOLOCK) ON c.actor_uid = users.actor_uid  INNER JOIN
                         users AS users_1 ON users.supervisor_uid = users_1.actor_uid

 INNER JOIN
                      actors_groups AS actors_groups WITH (NOLOCK) ON users.actor_uid = actors_groups.actor_uid INNER JOIN
                      groups AS groups WITH (NOLOCK) ON actors_groups.group_uid = groups.group_uid INNER JOIN
                      documents AS documents WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.document_uid= documents.document_uid INNER JOIN
                      actors AS actors_1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON users.actor_uid = actors_1.actor_uid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      sf_pages AS sf_pages WITH (NOLOCK) ON documents.document_uid = sf_pages.document_uid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      sf_combo_values as sf_combo_values WITH (NOLOCK) ON sf_pages.sf_page_uid=sf_combo_values.sf_page_uid left outer join
                      sf_system_lookup_values AS sf_system_lookup_values WITH (NOLOCK) ON sf_combo_values.sf_system_lookup_value_uid=sf_system_lookup_values.sf_system_lookup_value_uid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      sf_system_lookup_values AS sf_system_lookup_values_1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON sf_combo_values.sf_system_lookup_value_uid=sf_system_lookup_values_1.sf_system_lookup_value_uid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      sf_system_lookup_tables AS sf_system_lookup_tables WITH (NOLOCK) ON sf_system_lookup_tables.sf_system_lookup_table_uid = sf_system_lookup_values_1.sf_system_lookup_table_uid LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      sf_system_prompts as sf_system_prompts WITH (NOLOCK) ON sf_system_prompts.sf_system_lookup_table_uid = sf_system_lookup_tables.sf_system_lookup_table_uid
WHERE     event_name='Closed' and (groups.group_type_uid = 1) AND (groups.group_uid = 1000) AND (actors_1.account_name IN (@Users)) AND (cast(c.event_date as date) BETWEEN 
                      @StartDateAdj AND @EndDateAdj) AND (users.supervisor_uid IN (@aSupeList))
GROUP BY users.last_name, actors_groups.group_uid, groups.name, users.actor_uid, users.first_name, documents.document_uid, documents.document_format_uid, groups.group_type_uid, a.event_date, 
actors_1.account_name, documents.document_id, users_1.last_name, users_1.first_name, sf_system_prompts.prompt, sf_system_lookup_values.lookup_name
```

Comment: A statement in SQL that returns results starts with `SELECT` (or perhaps `WITH`.  Your expressions don't return results, except in the context of a larger query.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't include my entire query, since it's a bit long.  But I'll add it now thanks.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: I think your query should work if you just add all the columns in group by clause except columns being used in MAX(CASE..)...